# A loop but selective numbers

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have to retrieve data from an API. 
Certain data has to be retrieved in a certain order.

To be exact, data needs to be retrieved in this order:

```
7,40,8,9,10,45,11,39,5,12,13,15,6,18,0,46,22,23,3,41,1,24,42,25,26,4,27,2
```

So when loop is doing 0, then it needs to retrieve data number 7, when loop is doing 1, then data number 40 and if loop is doing 2 then data number 8 etc.

listWithDataFromAPI I do this:

```
 metricsSheet.appendRow([listWithDataFromAPI.symbols]);
```

And get this response:

```
[Ljava.lang.Object;@1e1aaea2
```

When I insert a specific number I do this:

```
 metricsSheet.appendRow([listWithDataFromAPI.symbols].symbols[8]]);
```

And get such response: `{name=DataPeter, longVolume=6640.87, longPositions=23678}`

Thus if loop is 0 then extract 7, loop is 2 extract 40 etc. as I mentioned.

This is what I'm trying in concept:

```
 var listNumberValue = ["5","30","7"]; 
 var symbols = listWithDataFromAPI.symbols;  

 for (var i in listNumberValue) {
  var symbol = symbols[listNumberValue];
   metricsSheet.appendRow([symbol.name]);
 }
```

Hope this makes sense.
Not sure how to do this..?

Comment: I apologize for my poor English skill. Can you add more information for thinking of your issue? Can you explain about the relationship between ``numberValue`` and ``listWithDataFromAPI.symbols``? If you can do, could you please provide a sample values?

Comment: When I see what is in the listWithDataFromAPI I do this:

metricsSheet.appendRow([listWithDataFromAPI.symbols]);

An get this response:
[Ljava.lang.Object;@1e1aaea2

Comment: When I insert a spesific number I do this:

metricsSheet.appendRow([listWithDataFromAPI.symbols].symbols[8]]);

And get such response:

{name=DataPeter, longVolume=6640.87, longPositions=23678}

Comment: So I need a loop to extract certain data out of the listWithDataFromAPI, to be specific this data in this order: 7,40,8,9,10,45,11,39,5,12,13,15,6,18,0,46,22,23,3,41,1,24,42,25,26,4,27,2

Comment: Thus if loop is 1 then extract 7, loop is 2 extract 40 etc...

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about your situation from your replying. I think that this is due to my poor skill. I apologize for this. So in order to correctly understand your situation, can you update your question by including more information?

Comment: @Tanaike I have updated the question I hope it makes better sense now.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide the values of while data of ``listWithDataFromAPI``? Because from ``listWithDataFromAPI.symbols``, I couldn't image the original value and also I think that ``appendRow([listWithDataFromAPI.symbols].symbols[8]]); `` will occur an error. By these situation, I couldn't understand about your situation. The reason I couldn't image the original value from your question is due to my poor skill. I apologize for this. Of course, please remove your personal information. Even if you cannot do, don't worry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The big problem for us is that we don't know what `listWithDataFromAPI` is and you have not explained it.  But I think you're trying to say that you want to iterate over something that you can get from it so I took a stab at what I think you're trying to do.

The first function will take your 0 through 46 indexes and reorder as 7,40,8,9,10,45,11,39,5,12,13,15,6,18,0,46,22,23,3,41,1,24,42,25,26,4,27,2

As shown in this table.

[image]

```
function getIdxObj() {
  var idxA=[7,40,8,9,10,45,11,39,5,12,13,15,6,18,0,46,22,23,3,41,1,24,42,25,26,4,27,2];
  var idxObj={};
  for(var i=0;i<idxA.length;i++) {
    idxObj[i]=idxA[i];
  }
  return idxObj;
}
```

The second function loops over symbols which apparently come from listWithDataFromAPI.symbols which has not been explained and so we know nothing about it.

```
function theUnknownFunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('metrics');//not sure about this either
  var idxObj=getIdxObj();
  var symbols = listWithDataFromAPI.symbols;  //I dont have a clue as to what listWithDataFromAPI is      
  for (var i=0;i<symbols.length;i++) {
    var symbol = symbols[idxObj[i]];
    sh.appendRow([symbol.name]);
  }
}
```

Comment: This helped, thank you!
I managed to get it going based on your logic :)